# How to get all users ever paid/complete an order?

Tags: php, magento

I am working on a custom Magento Extension.

Here is how I take all customers in a customer group:

```
$customers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach($customers as $customer)
{
    $email=$customer->getEmail();
    $CustomerPhone = $customer->getPrimaryBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
    $CustomerName = $customer->getName();
    $CustomerEmail = $customer->getEmail();
}
```

This how I get information about the users in a specific customer group.

How I can get all the users ever paid or complete (for example) an order?

Answer (score 0):

This is 90% of the way there:

```
<?php
require_once '<path_to_magento_root>/app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');

$customers = Mage::getResourceModel('reports/customer_collection')
  ->setPage(0,10)
  //->addAttributeToFilter('orders_count', array('gt' => 0))
  ->addOrdersStatistics();

foreach ($customers as $c) {
  echo $c->getId().' - '.$c->getEmail().': '.$c->getOrdersCount()." orders, average amount ".$c->getOrdersAvgAmount().", sum amount ".$c->getOrdersSumAmount().PHP_EOL;
}
```

The missing 10% is that this lists all customers, and their order information, rather than only ones with at least one order (which will include in-progress orders - the `addOrdersStatistics()` includes any orders that aren't canceled).

I have that commented line in there, `//->addAttributeToFilter('orders_count', array('gt' => 0))`, because I *thought* that should do it, but it appears to be doing nothing at all. Still, I figured I'd put this much up at least, because maybe it's at least a step in the right direction.

Of course, you also could just loop through every order, and build an array of customers that fit your criteria, but that's probably going to be much, much slower than using Magento's reports models like this. As a last resort, though, it'd work. So would querying the database directly, for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try following solution this should work for you.

```
    $customers = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        $customers->joinTable(
                array('sales/order'),
                'customer_email=email',
                array('*'),
                null,
                'right'
            ); 
   // print_r($customers->getData());

$data = $customers->getData();
foreach($data as $d)
{
    //print_r($d); // print this to see the available fields 
    echo $d[customer_email]; //get the desired information
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: I have to call this before `foreach($customers as $customer) { }` ?

Comment: @TonyStark Actually what do you want to perform? Why specifically before foreach loop?

Comment: I don't see any loop in your example. I want to perform mass SMS sending to all customers who have ever completed an order. I mean successfully paid an order. So for that reason i think i need foreach loop.

Comment: Are you sure that this code is selecting only users who have ever completed or paid order ?

Comment: @TonyStark Yes, to test this you create some customers on your localhost magento and place order.For some customers you should not place orders then run this script and compare with admin sales order section.

Comment: @TonyStark If you means by completed order means who placed at least one order. Then my code works correctly.